# Mongo DB: Single collection per user whit all interaction, or Multiple Collections per argument?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, project

Good Evening.
I'm pretty new to mongo db and i'm planning to make an app who will work whit Nosql(MongoDB).
The scope of the app is pretty simple:
Register a profile
Request item to a shopper
Fulfill and sent payment notice.

If i would make this whit SQL i would create a User Table, A Request Item Table a sending Paymen Table.

I would, also in order to learn something, to make it whit NOsql, and i choose mongo.
I could create 3 collection and put every different document and make a search every time i need.
OR, and this is the question, COULD i create collection for EVERY user, and inside every user put every interaction of the very same user.
So if i need to search for User10 order and paymen, i would look only inside User10 collection and search for every item he\she requested.

But on the other hand, how much can affect me if i need to search all order in a specific timeframe? It should be slower than SQL i suppose.

Is a acceptable way to do this, there are some backdraw i did not *yet* seen, or is discouraged in order to make another approach?

The backend would be write in Java, meanwile the app (for...reason) would be write in Xamarin.Form
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is possible I would personally recommend against this as this is considered an anti pattern, you should read [this](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/schema-design-anti-pattern-massive-number-collections/#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20we%20recommend%20limiting,database%20and%20remove%20unnecessary%20collections.) article about this very topic.

I would personally ask myself what are the advantages of this approach that i'm hoping to gain? if quick queries at a user level is what you seek this should not be a problem with sufficient indexes. (on user_id and on timeframe ).

There are other standard solutions built to deal with scale like collection [sharding](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/). From my personal experience MongoDB deals with scale very well, It sounds like this is a personal project to learn from which probably means you'll never really reach hyper scale, The first barrier you'll probably encounter is hardware.